# How to print selected dropdown value?

Tags: php, html, forms

We have a quote reply form, We want to display the customer that this service will be completed in a minimum and maximum in time. For this, we have made two drop downs.

1. Min Time Duration
2. Max Time Duration.

When both the selected value is sent, how can it be displayed in the answer?

```
  <form method="post" class="quotation-reply default-hidden" id="editquotationreply">
  <div class="clearfix row input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">

if($time_duration = 15){
                $timeduration = array(15 => esc_html__('15 Mins', 'service-finder'),30 => esc_html__('30 Mins', 'service-finder'),45 => esc_html__('45 Mins', 'service-finder'),60 => esc_html__('1 Hr', 'service-finder'),75 => esc_html__('1 Hr 15 Mins', 'service-finder'),90 => esc_html__('1 Hr 30 Mins', 'service-finder'),105 => esc_html__('1 Hr 45 Mins', 'service-finder'),120 => esc_html__('2 Hrs', 'service-finder'),150 => esc_html__('2 Hrs 30 Mins', 'service-finder'),180 => esc_html__('3 Hrs', 'service-finder'),210 => esc_html__('3 Hr 30 Mins', 'service-finder'),240 => esc_html__('4 Hrs', 'service-finder'));
            }
                ?>

<select class="sf-select-box form-control sf-form-control" name="min_timeduration" data-live-search="true" title="<?php esc_html_e('Time Duration', 'service-finder'); ?>">
                <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Max Time Duration', 'service-finder'); ?></option>
                <?php
                if(!empty($timeduration)){
                    foreach($timeduration as $key => $value){
                        echo '<option value="'.esc_attr($key).'">'.esc_html($value).'</option>';    
                    }
                }
                ?>
              </select>  </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is min time code?

Answer (score 0):

Is your page reloaded after submitting the form and after that the selected value should show as selected? In this case you could use PHP's `$_SESSION` variable to store the selected `$key` and in the `foreach` loop you can check for this variable and add a `selected´ to the corresponding option.

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['min_timeduration'])) {
    $_SESSION['selected']  = $_POST['min_timeduration'];
}
$timeduration = [...];
foreach($timeduration as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($key) .'"';
    if(!empty($_SESSION['selected']) && $_SESSION['selected'] == $key) {
        echo ' selected ';
    }
    echo '>'. esc_html($value) .'</option>';    
}
```

Comment: As you said, we tried but did not succeed. Showing error. Will you explain to me detail right code? Yes, the page reloaded after submitting the form. Please see the screenshots:
http://prntscr.com/nbcy0h

http://prntscr.com/nbcyei

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in your second screenshot? It does not look like valid code for me (according to your syntax highlighting).

Comment: Sir, we are looking at this error. ( Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING  ) Please help us in establishing the correct code.

Comment: It looks like your whole HTML is echoed and encapsulated in '. I‘m using the same character for my array Index. Either change your encapsulation to “ or my array Index notation to “. Hint: Look at the highlighting in your editor, it shows that not everything is identified as PHP correctly.

Comment: Sir, We not understand what are you saying. Please explain to me code example.

Comment: Can you share your whole code as code and not as screenshot please? I don‘t want to retype everything. Create a pastebin or something similar.